# How can i change array in directive, and then reflect that change in my controller?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I made directive with isolated scope with "=" method, in that directive i pass empty array, then i push data on that array.... How that change can be reflected on original array in my controller?

Here is the example:

```
angular.module('myModule').controller('MyController', ['$scope', function($scope) {

        $scope.test = [];

    }]);

angular.module('myModule').directive('mydirective', function() {

    return {
        scope: {
            test: "=",
            bread: "="
        },
        restrict: 'E',
        link: function(scope, element, attribute) {

            scope.test.push('one more')

        },
        replace: true,
        templateUrl: 'some template'
    };
});
```

HTML

```
 <div ng-controller='MyController'>
     <mydirective test='test'></mydirective>

     <div ng-bind='test'> </div>

   </div>
```

**When i push something on array i dont have a reflection of that in my controller. 
How can i fix that?**

Comment: Is your code complete? You don't seem to be passing a scope variable from your controller to the directive in the first place.

Comment: @Starscream1984 well, you'd pass the `$scope` to the controller from the directive, not the other way around - either way OP has this wrong

Comment: yes i passed, this is just  simplified example of my real problem. I pass array test to directive, then i put something on that array inside directive, and change doesn't reflect in my controller

Comment: seems your dependency injection is wrong for controller, check that too

Comment: guys everything works this is just a mockup of my real problem, everything works except this reflection in controller

Comment: removed my answer as it has been made irrelevant by the code edits in OP

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to do what you are trying to achieve.

*HTML*

```
<!-- myCtrl contains the original array, which we push here to the scope as 'ctrl' -->
<div ng-controller='myCtrl as ctrl'>
  <!-- we pass your directive 'ctrl.test', which tells angular to two-way bind to the
       test property on the 'ctrl' object on the current scope -->
  <mydirective test='ctrl.test'>
    <!-- we're inside the isolate scope: test here refers to mydirective's idea of test,
         which is the two-way bound array -->
    <div ng-bind='test'></div>
  </mydirective>
</div>
```

*JS*

```
angular.module('app', [])
  .directive('mydirective', function() {
    scope: {
      test: '='
    },
    link: function($scope) {
      $scope.test.push('one more');
    }
  })
  .controller('myCtrl', function() {
     this.test = [];
  });
```

Any alterations to the array will now be reflected in the `ng-bind`. Please note that it is bad practice to place primitives on `$scope` without being part of an object (due to the mechanics of prototypical inheritance) so you'd want to change `$scope.test` to something else.

Comment: my div with ng-bind is not inside the directive

Comment: you can move the `ng-bind` outside as long as it's inside the same div as `myCtrl`